# Continuity Markup now showing in Preview

Tags: catalina, preview, continuity

I have an iPhone XS max with iOS 13.5.1 and a MacBook Pro mid 2015 with macOS Catalina 10.15.5. That should satisfy Continuity Markup system requirements.

I can do Continuity Markup with Quick View, with Screenshot's Floating Thumbnail, but, surprisingly, not with Preview. The icon is simply not there to click.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Both devices were recently restarted.

[image: QuickView]
[image: Preview]

Comment: I don't think Preview supports Continuity Markup.  I've never seen the button there in the past.

Comment: The documentation states that it is supported.

Comment: I could be reading [this page wrong](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mark-up-files-mchl1fd88863/10.15/mac/10.15) but it doesn't list Preview here: "When using Quick Look on your Mac, click the Markup tool . Or when using Quick Actions, choose Markup. Markup is also available in various apps, such as Mail, Notes, TextEdit, and Photos."

Comment: @fsb please explain https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/annotate-a-pdf-prvw11580/mac this page.

Comment: I don't know, that link only shows the Annotate button if you follow [these steps](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204975) exactly.  The button isn't in Preview any other time for me.  Following those directions I was able to see and use the button to get my Pencil markups into Preview.

Comment: Then it must be that the documentation about annotating PDFs is misleading.

Comment: BigSur documentation also lists the ability to use Annotate on iPad or iPhone when in Preview https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/annotate-a-pdf-prvw11580/11.0/mac/11.0

Comment: I'm able to get this feature to work by following the steps in Apple's support page.  I'll add my info as an answer as it does work.

Answer (score 4):

The Apple documentation about Continuity Markup is not as clear as it could be.  The only way to get Continuity Markup to work is follow the steps in [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204975).

You just can't open a doc in Preview and get this to work.  The Continuity Annotate button you indicated will not be displayed on the toolbar unless you follow these steps.  It's not one of those buttons that are displayed all the time in Preview.

1. Continuity Sketch and Continuity Markup work when your compatible devices are near each other and set up as follows:

   - Your Mac and iPad, iPhone, or iPod touch have Wi-Fi and Bluetooth turned on.
   - Your Mac and iPad, iPhone, or iPod touch are signed in to iCloud with the same Apple ID using two-factor authentication.
   - Your Mac is using macOS Catalina, and your iPad, iPhone, or iPod touch is using iPadOS or iOS 13.
2. **From the Finder on your Mac**, find the PDF or image that you want to mark up. Then take one of these actions:

   - Select the document, then press Space bar to open a preview window. Click the markup button  at the top of the window.
   - Or Control-click the document, then choose Quick Actions > Markup from the shortcut menu.
     From the markup toolbar at the top of the preview window, click the annotate button, in my case it was the iPad icon [image].

When this is done, the document will open on the iPhone/iPad automatically and you can start making changes.  Changes made on one device will be shown in the other device, too.

I followed the steps and was able to see my iPad icon in the toolbar and get this feature to work:
[image]

Comment: I have no problem to get Continuity Markup following steps you described. My beef here is that the Apple's documentation consistently states "Annotate the item by sketching or drawing on it using your nearby iPhone or iPad . If both devices are nearby, click , then choose a device" *in the Preview documentation*. This description should not be there and is misleading.

Comment: You're taking one sentence out of context. You can use Preview to annotate a pdf. The page you reference has links to other pages that explain the requirements for the feature. It works as Apple described and as you've seen. I can't change the Apple docs. Your question is about how to get CM to work, not about how the doc is written, this answers your question. You can provide feedback to Apple and hopefully they can take another look at their doc.

Comment: Respectfully, I disagree. My question was to make it work in Preview, as described in the documentation. The title of the document is "Annotate a PDF in Preview on Mac" and the title of the table is "Use the tools in the toolbar". With this given, to me, it is clear that the documentation communicates that this is something that should work. If it was the intention of the documentation to simply point me to Continuity Markup, that intention should not be communicated to me in the table where all of the thirteen annotation tools of Preview program are documented, but in the See Also section.

Comment: Update: I notified Apple again about the misleading documentation. Thank you for your time and effort to describe how to make Continuity Markup to work in general.

Comment: Hi @Rade_303, I've submitted a bug report as well. Honestly, can't explain this limitation other than a bug (as an intentional limitation is illogical...). Regards!

Answer (score 3):

I agree that "Preview" applications doesn't support Continuity Markup, for no reason. Continuity Markup only works on "Quick Look".
So pressing Space bar on the file (opens Quick Look) is ok. But double-click (opens Preview) not good for iPad annotations.